# How do to add validation to my calculator in c#

Tags: c#, validation, calculator

I'm creating a calculator and I want to add validation code in it, so that if anything besides numbers is entered, an error message appears.

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int R = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);

    int I = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);

    int number2;
    if (int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out number2))
    {
        int E = R - I;

        textBox3.Text = E.ToString(); 
    }
    else 
    { 
        textBox2.Text = ("value entered is not whole number"); 
    }
}
```

This is the code I am trying to use but it comes up with an error message when I enter a non-numeric value.

Comment: If this is C#, why tag it with C?

Comment: You should use TryParse when you're attempting to convert both values. If either fails, there's non-numeric values in the textbox and you can pop up an error message box or something.

Comment: Or one better, try and use a tryparse on text change, since I'm presuming this isn't anything too overly complex.  On a different note, depending on what it is, you might consider allowing values other than just int (for example decimal values should probably be allowable for most types of calculators, unless it's somehow actually out of the scope of the project)

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `Convert.ToInt32` method before `TryParse` and that causes the exception. Don't do that, do the validation with `TryParse`.

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int R, I;

    if (int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out R) &&
        int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out I))
    {
         int E = R - I;

         textBox3.Text = E.ToString(); 
    }
    else 
    {
       MessageBox.Show("You have entered an invalid value!");
    }
}
```

Also you might consider using more descriptive variable names instead of `E`, `R`, `I`...

Comment: Thank you very much sorry im new at this

Comment: In this case, E, R, and I might be okay, but generally speaking it's sort of bad practice.  If this was something larger, you'd want to name your variables something that you'd actually be able to make sense out of it later if you had to come back and maintain the code a few weeks (or even months) down the line.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int R, I;
    if (int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out R)
    && int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out I))
    {
        int E = R - I;
        textBox3.Text = E.ToString(); 
    }
    else { textBox3.Text = ("value entered is not whole number"); }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you try to parse the strings into ints with `TryParse` always, rather than just converting immediately... if there are letters, the conversion fails.

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int number1;
    int number2;
    if (int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out number1) && int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out number2))
    {
      //do your thang (subtraction, assigning the result to TextBox3)
      //return
    }
    else
    {
      MessageBox.Show("Oh no you entered something that's not an int!");
    }
}
```

I might also add that making the value of one of your input text boxes "Value entered is not a whole number" is kind of a weird UI experience. I'd mark the textbox in red or pop up a message box or something instead, leaving the entered value in the box, in case it was some really long number like 879320!78 where they accidentally entered a weird symbol or something.